# Serializing list to file

Tags: android

I would like to ask for your advice,
I have a list of items which r binded to database, and i want to serialize those items(through my database) to file, and in the future to deserialize them.
now as we know, i have to go through all the rows in my database and create new object to each row and serialize the "object packadge" to the file.
the prob is that if we have 10000 rows in my database, then it's 10000 allocations of objects..
any idea how to avoid it?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Most databases should have some sort of "dump" functionality that allow you to save off parts of the database.

Comment: Do you want to do this during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html:

> From an adb remote shell, you can use
>   the sqlite3 command-line program to
>   manage SQLite databases created by
>   Android applications. The sqlite3 tool
>   includes many useful commands, such as
>   .dump to print out the contents of a
>   table and .schema to print the SQL
>   CREATE statement for an existing
>   table. The tool also gives you the
>   ability to execute SQLite commands on
>   the fly.

Comment: Yes, but when you say on the fly.. can i code from inside my app?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you want it on runtime. I am not sure if it's possible. :(